# Collections Referencing in MongoDb and fetching data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Issue with Creating Relations in Collection in MongoDB to fetch Data through REST API

I am new to NodeJs and MongoDB, I am trying to develop a REST API that fetched data for categories and products. I am trying to create a relation b/w the categories and product such that when queried for a particular category, only those products should be fetched from the DB

I have tried fetching data from categories and then passed the _id into products to fetch the related products.

## Categories.js Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator')

const categoriesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { 
        type: String,
        unique: true,
    }
})
categoriesSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator)
module.exports = mongoose.model('Categories', categoriesSchema)
```

## Prodcuts.js Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const  ProductSchema =  mongoose.Schema({
    category:{
    type: String
    },
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true
    } ,
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true
    } ,
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        default:0
    } ,
    color: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true
    } ,
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        default:0
    } 
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

## Home.js Route

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const productModel = require('../models/products')
const categoriesModel = require('../models/categories')


router.get('', async (req, res) => {
    categroyFetched = []
    productsFecthed =[]
    await categoriesModel.find({})
        .then(categories => {
            categroyFetched = categories.map(category => {
                return{
                    name: category.name, 
                    id: category._id
                }
            })

            return category = {
                count: categroyFetched.length,
                name: categroyFetched
            }
        })
       .then(async()=>{
        await productModel.find({category: categroyFetched.id})
        .then(products => {

            productsFecthed = products.map(product => {
                return product
            })

        })

       })
       .catch(err => {
        console.log('err', err)
    })

    res.status(200).json({
        category, productsFecthed
    })

})

module.exports = router
```

I need help in establishing the relation in Category and Products Schema and later how I can use it in Home.js Route to extract Data. and Also while creating the Products, what format of Json Data need to be sent to incorporate reference to Category Collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to establish relationship between Category and Product define your Product schema as follows:

```
const  ProductSchema =  mongoose.Schema({
    category:{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Categories" },  
 // other fields...
```

Now in order to insert record in product, category will take `ObjectId` (in other words, _id of Category) of Category.

Now you can query and do whatever you want.

```
await Product.find().populate('category') // This will also populate category along with product

await Product.find({category: catId}).populate('category'); //conditional find statement
```

Comment: Keeping ref as **Product** in ProductSchema will help establish the relationship with Categories Schema?
isn't Product self referencing in the code you have mentioned? and it should be **ref: "Categories"**?

Comment: also to be sure, we always give "ref" value that we use it to pass in the model, right?
in my code, it will be **Categories** ?

Comment: Ya.. in your case use Categories.

Comment: conditional statement isn't working. I am getting an empty array "productsFecthed": [] for the Product query  <br/>                                      
**await productModel.find({category: '5d2ecd601c9d4400006577c9'}).populate('category')**

Comment: convert it to ObjectId. `await productModel.find({category:ObjectId('5d2ecd601c9d4400006577c9')}).populate('category')`

Comment: Also, what do you think of the approach I am following in Home.js Router File  <br/>Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

For your flow,

We will start with creating categories and saving them in DB, then when creating products we will fetch all categories from DB and show in UI for selection of category to create products. Every created product would have a category as string in the DB(as you described in schema).

Now If we want to fetch products of a specific category, try `productModel.find({category: specificCategory})` if category is saved as string in the product. Here specific category is what you sent to the server. In your query, if you are planning to store both `name` and `id` of a category in product. Then you should have to change the category from string to object in the product schema. When saving product you should send object containing name and id to the product.

If you want to fetch all categories with the related products for each category at the same time, try `$lookup` aggregations queries in mongodb. They are very useful to perform operations on multiple collections in a single query.

Comment: I understand saving categories first in DB and then creating products with category name as string.
1) But how do you establish the relation between these two collections?
2) I am only planning to save Category Id in Product Schema so that I can somehow establish relationship of one to many(category to Products) in the DB
3) I am aware of the $lookup aggregations but am I am unable to implement it in my Home.js Route file. Any code snippet would help in context to my file

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using category id to make a relation. In product schema update categoryId key from `string` to `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`. This will be useful when performing aggregations based on category id relation. Now after creation of category and product, the documents in DB will have same key which can be used as a relation between the related documents.

If you are choosing $lookup to perform the query in you question, then in the Home.js

```
categoriesModel.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "product",
         localField: "_id",
         foreignField: "categoryId",
         as: "products"
       }
  }
])
```

Expected Result will be array of all categories with products as key for every element. products are the array of products of the respective category

`[{name:'category1', products:[{p1 Object},{p2 Object}, ...{}]}, {name:'category2', products:[{p6 Object},{p7 Object}, ...{}]}]`. Try this.

Comment: what will "db" be defined as?
 Got a reference error

Comment: Updated the snippet @YatinKapur